# LWIP packet length

Tags: tcp, stm32, lwip, mbedtls

I have a problem with the mbedtls server (stm32+lwip) send wrong length message. I am using this code in my project.
https://github.com/straight-coding/straight-httpd-lwip-mbedtls-simulator

[image: Wireshark packet trace. A TLSv1.2 "server hello" packet is selected]

Server hello message include 150 byte message but in the packet details this message should be 576 byte.
[image: Selected packet is showing a red warning: "IPv4 total length exceeds packet length (136 bytes)"]

When I checked the low_level_output function I can only see 150 byte data, why the packet length is wrong ? How can I solve the problem ?

This is mbedtls debug output:

```
line, 2 level,file  message: => handshake
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 0
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 1
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 1325 line, 2 level,file  message: => parse client hello
: 1860 line, 2 level,file t message: => fetch input
: 2022 line, 2 level,file t message: in_left: 0, nb_want: 5
: 2046 line, 2 level,file t message: in_left: 0, nb_want: 5
: 2047 line, 2 level,file t message: ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 5 (-0xfffffffb)
: 2067 line, 2 level,file t message: <= fetch input
: 1357 line, 4 level,file  message: dumping 'record header' (5 bytes)
: 1357 line, 4 level,file  message: 0000:  16 03 01 00 cb                                   .....
: 1369 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, message type: 22
: 1378 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, message len.: 203
: 1381 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, protocol version: [3:1]
: 1860 line, 2 level,file t message: => fetch input
: 2022 line, 2 level,file t message: in_left: 5, nb_want: 208
: 2046 line, 2 level,file t message: in_left: 5, nb_want: 208
: 2047 line, 2 level,file t message: ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 203 (-0xffffff35)
: 2067 line, 2 level,file t message: <= fetch input
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: dumping 'record contents' (203 bytes)
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0000:  01 00 00 c7 03 03 33 89 ee 0a c8 f4 8d 69 14 00  ......3......i..
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0010:  2d 50 69 44 70 4f fa 47 8e 73 e5 76 cf 2c 5a 63  -PiDpO.G.s.v.,Zc
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0020:  8f 78 af 8b 26 0f 00 00 38 c0 2c c0 30 00 9f cc  .x..&...8.,.0...
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0030:  a9 cc a8 cc aa c0 2b c0 2f 00 9e c0 24 c0 28 00  ......+./...$.(.
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0040:  6b c0 23 c0 27 00 67 c0 0a c0 14 00 39 c0 09 c0  k.#.'.g.....9...
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0050:  13 00 33 00 9d 00 9c 00 3d 00 3c 00 35 00 2f 00  ..3.....=.<.5./.
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0060:  ff 01 00 00 66 00 00 00 10 00 0e 00 00 0b 65 78  ....f.........ex
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0070:  61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 6f 72 67 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01  ample.org.......
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0080:  02 00 0a 00 0c 00 0a 00 1d 00 17 00 1e 00 19 00  ................
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 0090:  18 00 23 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 0d 00  ..#.............
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 00a0:  2a 00 28 04 03 05 03 06 03 08 07 08 08 08 09 08  *.(.............
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 00b0:  0a 08 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01 05 01 06 01 03  ................
: 1463 line, 4 level,file  message: 00c0:  03 03 01 03 02 04 02 05 02 06 02                 ...........
: 1481 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, handshake type: 1
: 1490 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, handshake len.: 199
: 1579 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'client hello, version' (2 bytes)
: 1579 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  03 03                                            ..
: 1610 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'client hello, random bytes' (32 bytes)
: 1610 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  33 89 ee 0a c8 f4 8d 69 14 00 2d 50 69 44 70 4f  3......i..-PiDpO
: 1610 line, 3 level,file  message: 0010:  fa 47 8e 73 e5 76 cf 2c 5a 63 8f 78 af 8b 26 0f  .G.s.v.,Zc.x..&.
: 1628 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'client hello, session id' (0 bytes)
: 1713 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'client hello, ciphersuitelist' (56 bytes)
: 1713 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  c0 2c c0 30 00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa c0 2b c0 2f  .,.0.........+./
: 1713 line, 3 level,file  message: 0010:  00 9e c0 24 c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27 00 67 c0 0a  ...$.(.k.#.'.g..
: 1713 line, 3 level,file  message: 0020:  c0 14 00 39 c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d 00 9c 00 3d  ...9.....3.....=
: 1713 line, 3 level,file  message: 0030:  00 3c 00 35 00 2f 00 ff                          .<.5./..
: 1733 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'client hello, compression' (1 bytes)
: 1733 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  00                                               .
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'client hello extensions' (102 bytes)
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  00 00 00 10 00 0e 00 00 0b 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65  .........example
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: 0010:  2e 6f 72 67 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 0c  .org............
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: 0020:  00 0a 00 1d 00 17 00 1e 00 19 00 18 00 23 00 00  .............#..
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: 0030:  00 16 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 0d 00 2a 00 28 04 03  ...........*.(..
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: 0040:  05 03 06 03 08 07 08 08 08 09 08 0a 08 0b 08 04  ................
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: 0050:  08 05 08 06 04 01 05 01 06 01 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
: 1788 line, 3 level,file  message: 0060:  04 02 05 02 06 02                                ......
: 1814 line, 3 level,file  message: found ServerName extension
: 1860 line, 3 level,file  message: found supported point formats extension
: 418 line, 4 level,file  message: point format selected: 0
: 1852 line, 3 level,file  message: found supported elliptic curves extension
: 1932 line, 3 level,file  message: found session ticket extension
: 1912 line, 3 level,file  message: found encrypt then mac extension
: 1922 line, 3 level,file  message: found extended master secret extension
: 1838 line, 3 level,file  message: found signature_algorithms extension
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 4 and hash 6
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 4 and hash 7
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 4 and hash 8
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 7
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 8
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 9
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 10
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 11
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 4
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 5
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 6
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 1 and hash 6
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 1 and hash 7
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 1 and hash 8
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 4 and hash 5
: 308 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: match sig 1 and hash 5
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 2
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 2
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 2
: 290 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext unknown sig alg encoding 2
: 2020 line, 3 level,file  message: received TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO 
: 936 line, 3 level,file  message: trying ciphersuite: TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
: 833 line, 3 level,file  message: ciphersuite requires certificate
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: candidate certificate chain, certificate #1:
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: cert. version     : 3
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: serial number     : 53:75:36:13:4F:C6:31:4A
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: issuer name       : CN=Straight RootCA
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: subject name      : CN=Straight Server
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: issued  on        : 2020-11-15 00:00:00
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: expires on        : 2040-11-15 00:00:00
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: RSA key size      : 512 bits
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: basic constraints : CA=false
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: subject alt name  :
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message:     dNSName : server
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message:     dNSName : straight
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: ext key usage     : TLS Web Server Authentication
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'crt->rsa.N' (512 bits) is:
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message:  84 3d 05 28 d7 47 f7 57 3c 56 2b 34 4f b3 e5 8b
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message:  71 ab 6f e0 4c e7 10 35 57 f8 8d 4c 67 ab e5 64
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message:  b0 26 50 1a 6f a9 49 e8 d3 61 ed 1d 79 01 73 8e
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message:  ed 73 83 3a ce 7c 8a 49 84 aa 05 a2 c1 a7 10 7f
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'crt->rsa.E' (17 bits) is:
: 845 line, 3 level,file  message:  01 00 01
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: selected certificate chain, certificate #1:
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: cert. version     : 3
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: serial number     : 53:75:36:13:4F:C6:31:4A
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: issuer name       : CN=Straight RootCA
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: subject name      : CN=Straight Server
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: issued  on        : 2020-11-15 00:00:00
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: expires on        : 2040-11-15 00:00:00
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: RSA key size      : 512 bits
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: basic constraints : CA=false
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: subject alt name  :
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message:     dNSName : server
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message:     dNSName : straight
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: ext key usage     : TLS Web Server Authentication
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'crt->rsa.N' (512 bits) is:
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message:  84 3d 05 28 d7 47 f7 57 3c 56 2b 34 4f b3 e5 8b
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message:  71 ab 6f e0 4c e7 10 35 57 f8 8d 4c 67 ab e5 64
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message:  b0 26 50 1a 6f a9 49 e8 d3 61 ed 1d 79 01 73 8e
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message:  ed 73 83 3a ce 7c 8a 49 84 aa 05 a2 c1 a7 10 7f
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'crt->rsa.E' (17 bits) is:
: 907 line, 3 level,file  message:  01 00 01
: 2123 line, 2 level,file  message: selected ciphersuite: TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
: 2147 line, 3 level,file  message: client hello v3, signature_algorithm ext: 4
: 2157 line, 2 level,file  message: <= parse client hello
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 2
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2589 line, 2 level,file  message: => write server hello
: 2623 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, chosen version: [3:3]
: 2647 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'server hello, random bytes' (32 bytes)
: 2647 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  3c ce d6 f9 48 cc 7d 5d 77 24 74 f2 1d 9f 8b aa  <...H.}]w$t.....
: 2647 line, 3 level,file  message: 0010:  4b 0c 20 64 d3 22 d0 ee 5e 3b 83 24 a7 01 ec d9  K. d."..^;.$....
: 2720 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, session id len.: 32
: 2721 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'server hello, session id' (32 bytes)
: 2721 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  39 44 75 59 8d 9f fd 10 16 21 18 ca e7 46 9e 5f  9DuY.....!...F._
: 2721 line, 3 level,file  message: 0010:  d0 72 aa 02 d9 51 e0 57 04 8d c6 dd f2 24 dd 39  .r...Q.W.....$.9
: 2723 line, 3 level,file  message: no session has been resumed
: 2730 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, chosen ciphersuite: TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
: 2732 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, compress alg.: 0x00
: 2342 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, secure renegotiation extension
: 2293 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, adding extended master secret extension
: 2413 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, supported_point_formats extension
: 2796 line, 3 level,file  message: server hello, total extension length: 15
: 2516 line, 2 level,file t message: => write handshake message
: 2675 line, 2 level,file t message: => write record
: 2793 line, 3 level,file t message: output record: msgtype = 22, version = [3:3], msglen = 91
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: dumping 'output record sent to network' (96 bytes)
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0000:  16 03 03 00 5b 02 00 00 57 03 03 3c ce d6 f9 48  ....[...W..<...H
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0010:  cc 7d 5d 77 24 74 f2 1d 9f 8b aa 4b 0c 20 64 d3  .}]w$t.....K. d.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0020:  22 d0 ee 5e 3b 83 24 a7 01 ec d9 20 39 44 75 59  "..^;.$.... 9DuY
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0030:  8d 9f fd 10 16 21 18 ca e7 46 9e 5f d0 72 aa 02  .....!...F._.r..
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0040:  d9 51 e0 57 04 8d c6 dd f2 24 dd 39 cc a8 00 00  .Q.W.....$.9....
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0050:  0f ff 01 00 01 00 00 17 00 00 00 0b 00 02 01 00  ................
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2099 line, 2 level,file t message: message length: 96, out_left: 96
: 2104 line, 2 level,file t message: ssl->f_send() returned 96 (-0xffffffa0)
: 2132 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2846 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write record
: 2652 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write handshake message
: 2815 line, 2 level,file  message: <= write server hello
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 3
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2093 line, 2 level,file  message: => write certificate
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: own certificate #1:
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: cert. version     : 3
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: serial number     : 53:75:36:13:4F:C6:31:4A
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: issuer name       : CN=Straight RootCA
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: subject name      : CN=Straight Server
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: issued  on        : 2020-11-15 00:00:00
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: expires on        : 2040-11-15 00:00:00
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: RSA key size      : 512 bits
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: basic constraints : CA=false
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: subject alt name  :
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message:     dNSName : server
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message:     dNSName : straight
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: ext key usage     : TLS Web Server Authentication
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'crt->rsa.N' (512 bits) is:
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message:  84 3d 05 28 d7 47 f7 57 3c 56 2b 34 4f b3 e5 8b
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message:  71 ab 6f e0 4c e7 10 35 57 f8 8d 4c 67 ab e5 64
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message:  b0 26 50 1a 6f a9 49 e8 d3 61 ed 1d 79 01 73 8e
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message:  ed 73 83 3a ce 7c 8a 49 84 aa 05 a2 c1 a7 10 7f
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'crt->rsa.E' (17 bits) is:
: 2142 line, 3 level,file  message:  01 00 01
: 2516 line, 2 level,file t message: => write handshake message
: 2675 line, 2 level,file t message: => write record
: 2793 line, 3 level,file t message: output record: msgtype = 22, version = [3:3], msglen = 488
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: dumping 'output record sent to network' (493 bytes)
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0000:  16 03 03 01 e8 0b 00 01 e4 00 01 e1 00 01 de 30  ...............0
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0010:  82 01 da 30 82 01 84 a0 03 02 01 02 02 08 53 75  ...0..........Su
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0020:  36 13 4f c6 31 4a 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d  6.O.1J0...*.H...
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0030:  01 01 0b 05 00 30 1a 31 18 30 16 06 03 55 04 03  .....0.1.0...U..
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0040:  0c 0f 53 74 72 61 69 67 68 74 20 52 6f 6f 74 43  ..Straight RootC
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0050:  41 30 1e 17 0d 32 30 31 31 31 35 30 30 30 30 30  A0...20111500000
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0060:  30 5a 17 0d 34 30 31 31 31 35 30 30 30 30 30 30  0Z..401115000000
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0070:  5a 30 1a 31 18 30 16 06 03 55 04 03 0c 0f 53 74  Z0.1.0...U....St
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0080:  72 61 69 67 68 74 20 53 65 72 76 65 72 30 5c 30  raight Server0\0
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0090:  0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03 4b  ...*.H.........K
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00a0:  00 30 48 02 41 00 84 3d 05 28 d7 47 f7 57 3c 56  .0H.A..=.(.G.W<V
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00b0:  2b 34 4f b3 e5 8b 71 ab 6f e0 4c e7 10 35 57 f8  +4O...q.o.L..5W.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00c0:  8d 4c 67 ab e5 64 b0 26 50 1a 6f a9 49 e8 d3 61  .Lg..d.&P.o.I..a
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00d0:  ed 1d 79 01 73 8e ed 73 83 3a ce 7c 8a 49 84 aa  ..y.s..s.:.|.I..
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00e0:  05 a2 c1 a7 10 7f 02 03 01 00 01 a3 81 ad 30 81  ..............0.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00f0:  aa 30 49 06 03 55 1d 23 04 42 30 40 80 14 83 84  .0I..U.#.B0@....
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0100:  e2 b3 b3 ed cc a3 9e 8e 7a 58 8e 30 cd 20 41 98  ........zX.0. A.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0110:  1a 7c a1 1e a4 1c 30 1a 31 18 30 16 06 03 55 04  .|....0.1.0...U.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0120:  03 0c 0f 53 74 72 61 69 67 68 74 20 52 6f 6f 74  ...Straight Root
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0130:  43 41 82 08 67 12 d4 80 49 b6 74 1c 30 1d 06 03  CA..g...I.t.0...
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0140:  55 1d 0e 04 16 04 14 1a ba 0a 36 d4 53 5d 0e e7  U.........6.S]..
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0150:  c5 e6 12 42 56 6a df 9a 15 40 34 30 0c 06 03 55  ...BVj...@40...U
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0160:  1d 13 01 01 ff 04 02 30 00 30 13 06 03 55 1d 25  .......0.0...U.%
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0170:  04 0c 30 0a 06 08 2b 06 01 05 05 07 03 01 30 1b  ..0...+.......0.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0180:  06 03 55 1d 11 04 14 30 12 82 06 73 65 72 76 65  ..U....0...serve
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0190:  72 82 08 73 74 72 61 69 67 68 74 30 0d 06 09 2a  r..straight0...*
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 01a0:  86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 03 41 00 3b 4d a3  .H.........A.;M.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 01b0:  27 0c 68 91 1e 02 78 0f 03 0c 9a a9 ff d4 24 d1  '.h...x.......$.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 01c0:  d8 a6 ff ff 9c 8d 54 e3 c6 a2 20 51 2e 72 90 d5  ......T... Q.r..
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 01d0:  b6 08 02 11 b8 fe 6b 57 2c cd bf a5 34 d8 5d 2a  ......kW,...4.]*
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 01e0:  f7 65 6c ff be 78 fd ea 7e 4f 24 fb d3           .el..x..~O$..
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2099 line, 2 level,file t message: message length: 493, out_left: 493
: 2104 line, 2 level,file t message: ssl->f_send() returned 493 (-0xfffffe13)
: 2132 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2846 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write record
: 2652 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write handshake message
: 2194 line, 2 level,file  message: <= write certificate
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 4
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 3436 line, 2 level,file  message: => write server key exchange
: 3214 line, 2 level,file  message: ECDHE curve: secp521r1
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'ECDH: Q(X)' (521 bits) is:
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  01 a4 3d 1f 0a f9 85 dc 1c 6b 55 b2 33 de 60 1b
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  c6 13 3c ee b9 c9 07 7f 63 fe b4 e6 65 43 36 08
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  cd 48 0e ab 39 88 0d 65 5d 93 79 d3 e9 3c 34 c5
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  b7 94 fc f1 e2 eb 16 64 37 65 98 ca 9a 4f 95 d1
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  05 75
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message: value of 'ECDH: Q(Y)' (518 bits) is:
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  31 6b 86 3a b2 34 b4 f6 4c 40 b5 d3 af fe f2 2d
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  7d a2 57 d9 79 ad 76 2e d1 14 14 88 22 5b 00 d1
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  a8 bf 1b 44 d5 46 95 59 df 5c d0 00 02 90 7e c4
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  b3 61 72 db 6b 33 81 a9 87 07 9b 3f 8d e8 36 34
: 3240 line, 3 level,file  message:  48
: 3303 line, 3 level,file  message: pick hash algorithm 6 for signing
: 7538 line, 3 level,file  message: Perform mbedtls-based computation of digest of ServerKeyExchange
: 3341 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'parameters hash' (32 bytes)
: 3341 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  ef 45 58 c8 60 14 a2 ca 26 31 c3 f0 f3 a0 c2 e0  .EX.`...&1......
: 3341 line, 3 level,file  message: 0010:  79 6b 30 1d 91 16 76 f9 df 6b 96 1e d9 06 15 31  yk0...v..k.....1
: 3501 line, 3 level,file  message: dumping 'my signature' (64 bytes)
: 3501 line, 3 level,file  message: 0000:  09 5c bb 24 ed be ed 5a ac 29 42 14 69 10 3b db  .\.$...Z.)B.i.;.
: 3501 line, 3 level,file  message: 0010:  b1 d2 d9 c1 84 3e f1 bd 5d b2 f4 9a b2 5b 13 be  .....>..]....[..
: 3501 line, 3 level,file  message: 0020:  fd ee 55 44 93 10 81 6c 4c 2c cb cb 86 e6 a9 a3  ..UD...lL,......
: 3501 line, 3 level,file  message: 0030:  b3 1c b1 69 02 1c cc 32 0e 7e b7 fc 13 61 16 93  ...i...2.~...a..
: 2516 line, 2 level,file t message: => write handshake message
: 2675 line, 2 level,file t message: => write record
: 2793 line, 3 level,file t message: output record: msgtype = 22, version = [3:3], msglen = 209
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: dumping 'output record sent to network' (214 bytes)
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0000:  16 03 03 00 d1 0c 00 00 cd 03 00 19 85 04 01 a4  ................
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0010:  3d 1f 0a f9 85 dc 1c 6b 55 b2 33 de 60 1b c6 13  =......kU.3.`...
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0020:  3c ee b9 c9 07 7f 63 fe b4 e6 65 43 36 08 cd 48  <.....c...eC6..H
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0030:  0e ab 39 88 0d 65 5d 93 79 d3 e9 3c 34 c5 b7 94  ..9..e].y..<4...
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0040:  fc f1 e2 eb 16 64 37 65 98 ca 9a 4f 95 d1 05 75  .....d7e...O...u
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0050:  00 31 6b 86 3a b2 34 b4 f6 4c 40 b5 d3 af fe f2  .1k.:.4..L@.....
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0060:  2d 7d a2 57 d9 79 ad 76 2e d1 14 14 88 22 5b 00  -}.W.y.v....."[.
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0070:  d1 a8 bf 1b 44 d5 46 95 59 df 5c d0 00 02 90 7e  ....D.F.Y.\....~
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0080:  c4 b3 61 72 db 6b 33 81 a9 87 07 9b 3f 8d e8 36  ..ar.k3.....?..6
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0090:  34 48 04 01 00 40 09 5c bb 24 ed be ed 5a ac 29  4H...@.\.$...Z.)
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00a0:  42 14 69 10 3b db b1 d2 d9 c1 84 3e f1 bd 5d b2  B.i.;......>..].
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00b0:  f4 9a b2 5b 13 be fd ee 55 44 93 10 81 6c 4c 2c  ...[....UD...lL,
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00c0:  cb cb 86 e6 a9 a3 b3 1c b1 69 02 1c cc 32 0e 7e  .........i...2.~
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 00d0:  b7 fc 13 61 16 93                                ...a..
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2099 line, 2 level,file t message: message length: 214, out_left: 214
: 2104 line, 2 level,file t message: ssl->f_send() returned 214 (-0xffffff2a)
: 2132 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2846 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write record
: 2652 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write handshake message
: 3520 line, 2 level,file  message: <= write server key exchange
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 5
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2851 line, 2 level,file  message: => write certificate request
: 2516 line, 2 level,file t message: => write handshake message
: 2675 line, 2 level,file t message: => write record
: 2793 line, 3 level,file t message: output record: msgtype = 22, version = [3:3], msglen = 23
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: dumping 'output record sent to network' (28 bytes)
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0000:  16 03 03 00 17 0d 00 00 13 02 01 40 00 0c 05 01  ...........@....
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0010:  05 03 04 01 04 03 02 01 02 03 00 00              ............
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2099 line, 2 level,file t message: message length: 28, out_left: 28
: 2104 line, 2 level,file t message: ssl->f_send() returned 28 (-0xffffffe4)
: 2132 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2846 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write record
: 2652 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write handshake message
: 3002 line, 2 level,file  message: <= write certificate request
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 6
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 3528 line, 2 level,file  message: => write server hello done
: 2516 line, 2 level,file t message: => write handshake message
: 2675 line, 2 level,file t message: => write record
: 2793 line, 3 level,file t message: output record: msgtype = 22, version = [3:3], msglen = 4
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: dumping 'output record sent to network' (9 bytes)
: 2796 line, 4 level,file t message: 0000:  16 03 03 00 04 0e 00 00 00                       .........
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2099 line, 2 level,file t message: message length: 9, out_left: 9
: 2104 line, 2 level,file t message: ssl->f_send() returned 9 (-0xfffffff7)
: 2132 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2846 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write record
: 2652 line, 2 level,file t message: <= write handshake message
: 3556 line, 2 level,file  message: <= write server hello done
: 4458 line, 2 level,file  message: server state: 7
: 2080 line, 2 level,file t message: => flush output
: 2092 line, 2 level,file t message: <= flush output
: 2731 line, 2 level,file  message: => parse certificate
: 3878 line, 2 level,file t message: => read record
: 1860 line, 2 level,file t message: => fetch input
: 2022 line, 2 level,file t message: in_left: 0, nb_want: 5
: 2046 line, 2 level,file t message: in_left: 0, nb_want: 5
: 5707 line, 2 level,file  message: <= handshake
```